# npcap sending raw packets in virtual machine allways fail ,how to fix it?

Tags: vmware, hyper-v, pcap, npcap

I wrote a piece of code ,which basically resent captured packets if the destination address is 172.16.2.3，

so I tried sending udp packet in python from 172.16.2.133 to 172.16.2.3:27180 and hopefully my code will duplicate it ,it worked ,172.16.2.3 recieved two udp packets will the same messages .

but after I installed windows in hyper-v (bridge mode)，and configured it to 172.16.2.132 (host machine ip 172.16.2.133)

it doesn't work anymore ,only the first udp send in python arrived ,the second is sent successfully (pcap_sendpacket return 0), but never arrived .

Then I tried vmware ,doesn't work either ,

I tried this method bellow, doesn't work .

https://superuser.com/questions/1043936/802-1x-with-hyper-v

so what exactly is preventing me from successfully sending raw packets in virtual machines ?